# R Forecast Package: Why are my in-sample simulations consistently higher than the original time-series when using the simulate function?

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

**What I want to do:**
Fit an arima model with an xreg component using auto.arima and then generate simulations in-sample where I pass in different xreg values.

**The issue:**
After fitting an arima model (using auto.arima) to a time-series (y), I do a simple check where I use the simulate function in-sample to predict the original time-series.  I expected any differences between the prediction and the original time-series to hover around zero.  However, no matter how simple or complicated my arima model is, the in-sample predictions are always greater than Y.  The difference appears to accumulate during the first few time-steps of the in-sample prediction and remains steady for the remaining time-steps being predicted.

**My questions:**

1. Can someone explain to me why my simulated in-sample predictions are
   always greater compared to the original time-series?
2. If I'm calling the function incorrectly, can someone tell me how I can produce a
   more accurate in-sample prediction (one that does not have a predictable bias)?
3. If the simulate function should not be used for this purpose, is there another way to perform in-sample predictions using the fitted arima model (that also supports changing the xreg variable if the arima model included xreg)?

Many thanks.

A example below:

```
library(forecast)

# Prepare y
y = rnorm(100)+seq(1,100,1)/10

# Fit arima model
mdl <- auto.arima(y,seasonal=FALSE)

# Perform in sample prediction using simulate function
prediction <- simulate(mdl,future = FALSE, bootstrap = FALSE, innov = residuals(mdl))

# Compare prediction to y
difference = prediction - y
plot.ts(difference); title('prediction always > Y')
mean(difference) # <-- always ends up being positive rather than close to zero
```

[image]

Comment: Hi: I've never used the forecast package but I don't think future should be FALSE. According to the vignette: future,  if TRUE, produces sample paths that are future to and conditional on the data in  the object. Otherwise, it simulates unconditionally. So, I think it's simulating unconditionally so essentially not the model you estimated.  In your case, I think you want to simulate using future = TRUE but I'm  not clear on what you're trying to do by simulating. I would email Robert Hyndman, the author of forecast,  but be clear on what you're trying to do.